# Android display another dialog from a dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I am trying to display a dialog from the onClick listener of a button of another dialog, but the 2nd dialog won't display. I searched and found a similar problem- [Dialogs order in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989767/dialogs-order-in-android), tried the solution provided, but even that does not work.

My code is very similar to the one provided in the answer.

> public void onClick(DialogInterface
>   dialog, int id) {
>               showDialog(SECOND_DIALOG);
>               dialog.dismiss();
>           }

any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks,

Akshay

Comment: Just Hide and Show Views On Dialog Clicks

Comment: I was able to display a `PopupWindow` from a `DialogFragment`, but attempting to display one from another `PopupWindow` gave a "WindowManagerBadTokenException".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how I'm doing it:

```
    if (!appPrefs.getAcceptedUsageAggrement()) {
        tracker.trackPageView("/UsageAgreementDialog");
        acceptedUsage_alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(BroadcastSMSActivity.this)
        .setTitle(R.string.accept_usage_title)
        .setMessage(R.string.accept_usage_message)
        .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        })
        .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                if (appPrefs.getAppVer().equals("")) {
                    tracker.trackEvent("Application", "Install", getAppVerName(), 1);
                } else {
                    tracker.trackEvent("Application", "Upgrade", appPrefs.getAppVer().toString()+"->"+getAppVerName(), 1);
                }
                displayRecentChanges = true;
                appPrefs.saveAppVer(getAppVerName());
                appPrefs.saveAcceptedUsageAggrement(true);
            // Display Recent Changes on 1st use of new version
                if (displayRecentChanges) {
                    tracker.trackPageView("/RecentChangesDialog");
                    recentChanges_alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(BroadcastSMSActivity.this)
                    .setTitle(getString(R.string.changes_title, getAppVerName()))
                    .setMessage(R.string.changes_dialog)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            recentChanges_alertDialog.cancel();
                            acceptedUsage_alertDialog.cancel();
                        }
                    })
                    .create();
                    recentChanges_alertDialog.show();
                }
            }
        })
        .create();
        acceptedUsage_alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Bill! This works! Apparently calling activity context's showDialog() doesn't.

Comment: I'm not certain that I have acceptedUsage_alertDialog.cancel(); in the right place, but I can tell you that when I cancelled it onClick() and then trying to create the subsequent dialog it caused a force close.  So, it seemed natural to me to just move it's .cancel() just after the 2nd dialog's cancel().

Comment: You might also note a couple of cool Google Analytics tricks in there ... I'm recording whether this run of the application was a new installation or an upgrade.  If it's an upgrade I'm recording the version their coming from and the version that's being installed: 1.5->1.8, etc.

Answer (score 7):

I know this was asked a while ago but here's a pretty neat solution I found.

I define an interface like this:

```
public interface OpenDialog {

public void showDialog(DialogFragment dialog);

}
```

Which my activity then implements, passing a reference to itself to the dialog when it's opened, using my InterfaceHolder class:

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OpenDialog {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);

    InterfaceHolder.set(this);        
    showDialog(new DialogOne());

}

public void showDialog(DialogFragment dialog) {
    dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "tag");
}
```

InterfaceHolder is just a class with a static reference to the interface I use to pass it around:

```
public class InterfaceHolder {
private static OpenDialog openDialog;

public void set(OpenDialog openDialog)
    this.openDialog = openDialog;
}

public void get()
    return openDialog;
}
```

So the showDialog method will display any dialog that I pass into it; as you can see, I do this to display DialogOne. Now, if I want to open a new dialog called "DialogTwo" inside "DialogOne" I can call it by writing:

```
InterfaceHolder.get().showDialog(new DialogTwo());
dismiss();
```

And voila, DialogTwo is shown. Obviously, you have to be careful to ensure that a reference to your activity has been passed to the InterfaceHolder (a nice way to do this is to put InterfaceHolder.set(this); inside the showDialog method), but otherwise this seems to work beautifully.

Answer (score 2):

my suggestion is this code. dialog 1 has a button when click it then dialog 2 will call.

```
    private Dialog dialog;
    private AlertDialog.Builder voteBuilder;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     

    // Firat dialog
            dialog = new Dialog(QrCodeReader.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customdialog_qr);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);

    // Second dialog
            showVotingDialog();

    //set up button of dialog 1
            Button btnVote = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnVote);
            btnVote.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    voteBuilder.show();
                }
            });

dialog.show();
    }

    private void showVotingDialog() {
            voteBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            voteBuilder.setTitle(R.string.votingdialog_title);
            voteBuilder.setCancelable(false);
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            final View checkboxLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.voting_dialog, null);
            voteBuilder.setView(checkboxLayout);
            voteBuilder.setPositiveButton(R.string.menu_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    RadioGroup radioGroup = (RadioGroup) checkboxLayout.findViewById(R.id.vote_radiogroup);
                    int checkedRadioButton = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                    int radioButtonSelected = 0;
                    switch (checkedRadioButton) {
                        case R.id.vote_item1 : radioButtonSelected = 1; break;
                        case R.id.vote_item2 : radioButtonSelected = 3; break;
                        case R.id.vote_item3 : radioButtonSelected = 5; break;
                        case R.id.vote_item4 : radioButtonSelected = 10; break;
                        case R.id.vote_item5 : radioButtonSelected = 20; break;
                        default: radioButtonSelected = 0;
                    }

                    sendVoteBySMS(radioButtonSelected);
                }
            });
            voteBuilder.setNegativeButton(R.string.menu_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    QrCodeReader.this.finish();
                }
            });

            voteBuilder.create();
    //      voteBuilder.show();
        }
```