# Cannot cancel dialog after losing focus?

Tags: java, android, xml, algorithm, dialog

I display a dialog with a close button and a button to open a new dialog. The close button works fine unless I have opened a second dialog on top of the current one. I think my dialog loses focus and cannot close.

```
  public void anotherOne(View v){

        openDialog2(); //This opens another dialog on top of the current one

}
 public void closeDialog(View v){

        dialog.cancel(); //This works fine unless anotherOne() has been called and closed

}
```

How can I reattach focus to my current dialog even after opening and closing another dialog on top of the current one?

Comment: Post relevant code . Your code is not enough to understand the exact problem .

Comment: Instead of dialog.cancel() try  dialog.dismiss();

Answer (score 1):

You should cancel the first dialogue after canceling the second one in the second dialogue's onClick method

Refee this link [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662538/android-display-another-dialog-from-a-dialog)

EDIT:

Try setting cancelable property programmatically

```
dialog.setCancelable(true);//will cancel dialog onBackPressed() and when negative button clicked
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true); // will cancel when user touches screen outside the dialog's box
```

Comment: Hmm. Do you know if there is a way to approach this if the user wants to exit the second dialog using back button?

Comment: The cancel method only executes when it is explicitly called in your code, or when the user presses the BACK button when your cancelable Dialog is open, so it should work with back button, or you can override OnBackPressed. I believe the idea is to first cancel the second dialogue and then the first in this order, i think you can do it from onBackPressed too

Comment: I tried doing so, and it still is not working.     `@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        if(dialog.isShowing()){
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    }`

Comment: Despite canceling the first dialog, the second dialog still does not have focus

Comment: well, that's strange behavior , try adding manually cancelable property. Edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you use 2 dialog you can achieve that.

```
public void anotherOne(View v){
        openDialog2(); //Open dialog 2

}
 public void closeDialog(View v){
        dialog1.cancel(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After 10+ hours, I finally figured it out! The mistake was very simple. I was using the **same** dialog object to control all of my dialogs. For example, I would initialize a dialog like so:

```
   generalDialog = new generalDialog(MainActivity.this);
   generalDialog.setContentView(R.layout.myLayout);
```

**Then I'd use the same dialog instance on another layout!!**

```
 generalDialog = new generalDialog(MainActivity.this);
 generalDialog.setContentView(R.layout.aDifferentFreakingLayout);
```

**Then, I'd expect my first dialog to close by doing this:**

```
generalDialog.cancel();
```

Instead, I should've just created two distinct objects and closed each one based on the situation!

Now that I look back at it, it seems like such a silly mistake! Hopefully this answer helps anyone else that is in the same situation! **Create different objects!!**

Comment: Yah, man, you didn't post all your code, the problem actually was strange as it should have worked from the beginning! Great you solved your issues!

Comment: @Rainmaker You're right! Thank you so much for your help though, it guided me into getting at this answer! +1 :)